# How can I retrieve a list of all user names logged in to SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, statistics

How can I get all user names that are currently logged in to the system in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 9):

This is an oft-asked question, which Bjorn Furuknap nails in his article here: http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site